# Xcode quits unexpectedly while submitting app to the AppStore

Tags: xcode, crash, app-store

I just tried to upload a new binary to itunesConnect. But my Xcode permanently quits without any warnings. Validation was successful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open organizer, quit Xcode *(keep Organiser open)*, then submit again. Works!

Comment: same problem, does not work here.

Comment: Make sure that you closed ALL Xcode's windows. Let it crash, then open again, close xcode windows, and submit again.

Comment: That worked for me too. Clean->Archive->then close the xcode windows and keep the organizer window open, then submit and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Or just submit with [Application Loader](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf).